# Is it possible to mod_rewrite BASED on the existence of a file/directory and uniqueID?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, htaccess

My site currently forces all non-`www.` pages to use `www.`

Ultimately, I am able to handle all unique subdomains and parse correctly but I am trying to achieve the following (ideally with mod_rewrite):

When a consumer visits `www.example.com/john4`, the server processes that request as:
`www.example.com?Agent=john4`

Our requirements are:

- The URL should continue to show `www.example.com/john4` even though it was redirected to `www.example.com/index.php?Agent=john4`
- If a file (of any extension OR a directory) exists with the name, the entire process stops an it tries to pull that file instead:

  For example: `www.example.com/file` would pull up (`www.example.com/file.php` if `file.php` existed on the server. `www.example.com/pages` would go to `www.example.com/pages/index.php` if the `pages` directory exists).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Agent=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: RewriteBase in this case is not necessary. The code continues to fail (although from looking through your suggestion it seems it **should** work.

Comment: @JM4 "continues to fail" - Fail as in error? Or not the desired result? There could also be a conflict with existing code, since you mention a canonical `www` redirect and _handling of subdomains_ - presumably in .htaccess also? This new code should probably go _after_ any existing directives.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on MultiViews, you can do this, as it will search for `request-uri.*` first before running the RewriteRule.

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Agent=$1 [L]
```